# Check product availability on form - return stock.quants - Odoo v8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I need to check on my object lines for the locations on which the products are available, this are my classes:

```
class bsi_production_order(models.Model):
    _name = 'bsi.production.order'

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        if vals.get('name', 'New') == 'New':
            if vals.get('production_type') == 'budgeted':
                vals['name'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('bsi.production.budgeted') or '/'
            elif vals.get('production_type') == 'nonbudgeted':
                vals['name'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('bsi.production.non_budgeted') or '/'
            elif vals.get('production_type') == 'direct':
                vals['name'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('bsi.production.direct') or '/'
        return super(bsi_production_order, self).create(vals)

    name = fields.Char('Reference', required=True, index=True, copy=False, readonly='True', default='New')
    date = fields.Date(string="Production Date")
    production_type = fields.Selection([
        ('budgeted','Budgeted'),
        ('nonbudgeted','Non Budgeted'),
        ('direct','Direct Order'),
    ], string='Type of Order', index=True,  
    track_visibility='onchange', copy=False,
    help=" ")
    notes = fields.Text(string="Notes")
    order_lines = fields.One2many('bsi.production.order.lines', 'production_order', states={'finished': [('readonly', True)], 'cancel': [('readonly', True)]}, string="Order lines", copy=True)
    print_orders = fields.One2many('bsi.print.order', 'production_orders', string="Print Orders")
```

On `order_lines` I should know what product quantity is available by returning the view with all the quants from this product (`isbn`)

This is `bsi.production.line` object (referred by `order_lines` One2many field):

```
class bsi_production_order_lines(models.Model):
    _name = 'bsi.production.order.lines'

    production_order = fields.Many2one('bsi.production.order', string="Production Orders")
    isbn = fields.Many2one('product.product', string="ISBN", domain="[('is_isbn', '=', True)]")
    qty = fields.Float(string="Quantity")
    product_template = fields.Many2one('product.template', string="Product")
    consumed_qty = fields.Float(string="Consumed quantity")
    remaining_qty = fields.Float(string="Remaining quantity", compute="_remaining_func") #

    @api.onchange('qty', 'consumed_qty')
    def _remaining_func(self):
        if self.qty or self.consumed_qty:
            self.remaining_qty = self.qty +(-self.consumed_qty)
```

I've taken the Qty on Hand method from `product_template` as inspiration, so this is my method (on `bsi.production.order`):

```
@api.depends('order_lines', 'order_lines.isbn')
def _get_products(self):
    isbn = []
    product_variant_ids = isbn.search(domain)
    for prodtmpl in self.order_lines: 
        isbn += [x.id for x in prodtmpl.product_variant_ids]
    return isbn

@api.one
def _get_act_window_dict(self, name):
    mod_obj = self.env['ir.model.data']
    act_obj = self.env['ir.actions.act_window']
    result = mod_obj.xmlid_to_res_id(name, raise_if_not_found=True)
    result = act_obj.read([result])[0]
    return result

@api.multi
def action_open_isbn(self):
    isbn = self._get_products()
    result = self._get_act_window_dict('stock.product_open_quants')
    result['domain'] = "[('isbn','in',[" + ','.join(map(str, isbn)) + "])]"
    result['context'] = "{'search_default_locationgroup': 1, 'search_default_internal_loc': 1}"
    return result
```

Right now, it throws me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 546, in _handle_exception
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 583, in dispatch
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 319, in _call_function
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\service\model.py", line 118, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 316, in checked_call
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 812, in __call__
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 412, in response_wrap
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 948, in call_button
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 936, in _call_kw
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 399, in old_api
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\openerp\addons\bsi\models\models.py", line 1045, in action_open_isbn
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\openerp\addons\bsi\models\models.py", line 1030, in _get_products
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'search'
```

The error comes on this line `product_variant_ids = isbn.search(domain)`, I know it's kind of weird, but I need to define this since `product_variant_ids` isn't defined on my method, also, I need to check this on `product.product` model, not `product.template`.

How can I adapt this method accordingly?

**EDIT**

I've tried @afwanwh solution, but now `_get_act_window_dict` method throws me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 546, in _handle_exception
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 583, in dispatch
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 319, in _call_function
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\service\model.py", line 118, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 316, in checked_call
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 812, in __call__
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 412, in response_wrap
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 948, in call_button
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 936, in _call_kw
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 399, in old_api
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\openerp\addons\bsi\models\models.py", line 1669, in action_open_isbn
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 266, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\openerp\addons\bsi\models\models.py", line 1663, in _get_act_window_dict
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I think it's because of the decorator, but I'm not sure, this method originally looked like this:

```
def _get_act_window_dict(self, cr, uid, name, context=None):
    mod_obj = self.pool.get('ir.model.data')
    act_obj = self.pool.get('ir.actions.act_window')
    result = mod_obj.xmlid_to_res_id(cr, uid, name, raise_if_not_found=True)
    result = act_obj.read(cr, uid, [result], context=context)[0]
    return result
```

Comment: `isbn = []` is assigning an empty list to variable isbn, and the next line you try to call `search` on it. Exactly as the message says.
I haven't used the library you are using, but most likely in the first line you want to make some library call, not just take an empty list, right?

Comment: Yeah, but in this case I'm not sure on what to call, since it should be Odoo compliant

Comment: I don't know if I should just get rid of it, not 100% sure

Comment: And why do you need the `    product_variant_ids = isbn.search(domain)` line? What is it supposed to do? You don't seem to be using the variable `product_variant_ids` anywhere.

Comment: This line: isbn += [x.id for x in prodtmpl.product_variant_ids]

Comment: No. `prodtmpl.product_variant_ids` is not a reference to the local variable `product_variant_ids`.

Comment: But if I don't add it, then I have the Object has no attribute 'product_variant_ids', so I took a related method as an example, I'm probably wrong tho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you have to do this:

```
@api.depends('order_lines', 'order_lines.isbn')
def _get_products(self):
    isbn = self.env['product.product']
    for prodtmpl in self.order_lines: 
        isbn |= prodtmpl.isbn
    return isbn
```

and this line in your method `action_open_isbn`

```
result['domain'] = "[('isbn','in',[" + ','.join(map(str, isbn.ids)) + "])]"
```

[UPDATE] Second error:

```
@api.model
def _get_act_window_dict(self, name):
    mod_obj = self.env['ir.model.data']
    result = mod_obj.xmlid_to_object(name)
    if not result:
        # this is just fallback if module stock is not installed
        # make sure you installed module stock and give dependency in your module
        result = {
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'tree,form',
            'res_model': 'stock.quant',
            'name': 'Stock On Hand',
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        }
    else:
        result = result[0].read()[0]
    return result
```

Comment: Thank You so much, gonna try it ASAP :)

Comment: Thank You very much, I've edited my question if You have an idea? Please, Thank You again

Comment: your previous error was solved, the new error is another one. if you are not sure, use @api.multi as default.

Comment: Thank You very very much, super awesome

Comment: Yeah, you're right, if a new problem arises gonna open a new question for that, Thank You again